# How to display the value of string with its title using html format

Tags: android

I have same info String like...
String info1 ="yyy";
String info2 ="mmm";

Now I want to disply it in Html Format and bold As..

Our First Information:yyy
Our Second Information:mmm

Comment: what do you mean in html format? you want to display it in a WebView? as HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String info1 ="yyy"; String info2 ="mmm"; 
etmsg.setText(Html.fromHtml("First Info <b>"+info1+"</b>"+"<br/>Second Info <b>"+info2+"</b>"));
```

Comment: How to write if we want both info in different line

Comment: @AlamAbsar check updated answer..will need a UpVote for that..ha ha :)

Answer (score 1):

Below is example for the same.

```
textview.setText(
                Html.fromHtml(
                        "<b>" +info1 + "</b> " + "<font color=\"#000000\">" +
                        info2 + 
                        "</font>"+

                    ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you're using a textview :

`myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>"youString"</h2><br><p>"YourSecondString"</p>"));`

Answer (score 0):

First define your string in string.xml file which is under values folder in resources folder as:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <resources>    
                <string name="select"><b><h2>S</h2></b>elect</string>    
       </resources>
```

and then use them as
android:text="@string/select"...

Answer (score 0):

```
String info1 ="yyy"; 
String info2 ="mmm";
TextView txt;
txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + str1 + "</b>" +  "<br />" + 
                   "<small>" + str2 + "</small>" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pointing out that a SpannableStringBuilder may be an interesting alternative if you're looking for a non-HTML-based solution. This way you could for example also use an inline HTML-styled link (URLSpan) to not execute the default ACTION_VIEW on the provided URL, but have it launch a new activity - or anything else you like.

```
String boldText = getString(R.string.bold_text);
    String italicText = getString(R.string.italic_text);
    String strikethroughText = getString(R.string.strikethrough_text);
    String urlText = getString(R.string.url_text);
    
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    ssb.append(boldText);
    ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), ssb.length()-boldText.length(), ssb.length() , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(italicText);
    ssb.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), ssb.length()-italicText.length(), ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(strikethroughText);
    ssb.setSpan(new StrikethroughSpan(), ssb.length()-strikethroughText.length(), ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    ssb.append(" ");
    ssb.append(urlText);
    ssb.setSpan(new URLSpan("http://www.stackoverflow.com"), ssb.length()-urlText.length(), ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spannable_text);
    tv.setText(ssb);
```

Which will look as follows:

[image]

Other spans can be found as subclass of [CharacterStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/CharacterStyle.html). E.g. the [TextAppearanceSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/TextAppearanceSpan.html) allows you to do most of the above but then by using xml-declared styles. I've used it to create a Button with two lines of text with different styles (different text size and colour) applied to each line.